# Redirect from a Laravel controller to an external URL with data as POST

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.5 and trying to do integrate a payment processor (local one) into the solution I am building. The issue : The processor is giving data needed on requests as data that needs to posted, and the problem is that some of that data are confidential !

So if I integrate them as hidden inputs in the form and post them using JS or even as a normal form, any user could access that data.

The solution for me is to handle the request of the user (his choice of paying online) and from there, I redirect him to the payment gateway with a POST method that contains all the data needed by the procesor.

What I've tried so far is using Guzzle, but guzzle is somehow acting like an ajax request, actualy even like an API request, it waits for data to return, while I don't need it, in fact, I have to redirect the user so that he can enter his payment details and authorize the payment.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$processorData = [
    'NumSite' => 'XXXXXX',
    'Password' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'Amount' => $invoice->total,
    'Devise' => 'TND',
    'orderId' => $id,
    'PayementType' => 1,
    'EMAIL' => $user->email,
    'signture' => sha1('XXXXXX'.'XXXXXXX'.$id.$invoice->total.'TND')
];
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->post('https://preprod.gpgcheckout.com/Paiement_test/Validation_paiement.php',
    ['paiment' => $processorData]);
```

I also tried a redirect, a curl .. same thing.
What I'm looking to achieve is like posting some data on behalf of user choice but without letting anyone see the hidden fields in my source code (html page)

Thank you

Comment: Hey! why are you confused, which data you don't want the user to see ?

Comment: Hey @rummykhan , it is about processorData array data

Comment: Chaibi, Actually we don't hide the form from user, rather we re-validate the data when user id redirected after the payment and see if he tried to change anything or not. And if he did we just slap him with error

Comment: let's say I did so, after validation, I still have to perform a post to the processor .. if I do some validation, it means the controller will handle it, and by that way, the controller have to also redirect with a post

Comment: Actually there are multiple ways for accepting payments. and you don't need to let the request go through your controller, just put the url of the payment processor in the form post action.